# Cover children with box-shadow but keep them clickable

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to create an inset box shadow on an object while still keeping the children clickable.

I've made this example from some related topics I've found http://jsfiddle.net/S8Sm7/14/

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <a href="#">Click me if you can!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

#inner {
    background-color: #55A8FF;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

This example requires you to set the z-index of the inner div to a negative number to get the shadow to display properly. However, once you do that you can't click the link anymore.

My ultimate goal is to add a shadow to the right edge of a side menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the outer div pointer events none but that will make the child pointer event none as well so turn it on by auto

```
#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#inner {
    background-color: #55A8FF;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Sm7/15/

NOTE: IE10 & below don't support pointer-events - You can provide support for IE by using this script: https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Comment: @Johnny Solution just reminded me IE10 & below don't support pointer-events, His solution is also good but will require extra markups & will fail in many other scenarios -- Use https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill to provide IE support.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll add it to my project.

Answer (score 0):

"pointer-events" does not support IE10 and before.

There is another way by simply using another layer for the text where z-index is not assigned:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="text">
        <a href="#">Click me if you can!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Sm7/16/

Comment: While you can click the link now, the shadow no longer covers it.